# Any way to figure out if the app is opened directly or because of a notification

Tags: trigger.io

Was not able to figure out how to get hold of the launch options (if its even possible). Want to understand how to figure out the app launch mechanism - that is to say whether the app was launched by the user directly, or because of a notification. It would even be helpful when using the new Safari smart app banners.

Anybody with similar problem ? Any workaround or solutions to this ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect when the app has been opened by a push notification or using a custom url.

1) Push notifications - use our event module in conjunction with our integration with Parse to write codes that runs when a push notification is received with the app open, or when it is opened by a push:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/event.html#messagepushed-addlistener

2) Custom urls - use our urlhandler module to assign a listener:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/urlhandler.html

Comment: somehow just missed the urlhandler doc totally ! Thanks a bunch @Amir

Answer (score 5):

I use this code to find out if my Trigger.io app was opened by a Parse push notification:

```
var appLastResumed = new Date();

window.forge.event.appResumed.addListener(function() {
  window.appLastResumed = new Date();
  // additional code that runs when the app is resumed
});

window.forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function() {
  // this event fires every time a user clicks on a push notification 
  // no matter whether the app is already opened or not
  // so we need to detect whether this happened right after an appResumed event

  setTimeout( function() { // make sure the appResumed event is fired first
    if (new Date().getTime() - window.appLastResumed.getTime() < 1000) {
      // app was opened by a push notification
      // insert your code here
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. On a side note, very cool work with Hojoki...I'm a regular user !