# Trigger.IO: Knowing when app is opened via Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, trigger.io

Is there any way of knowing when the app is opened via a push notification? This would be useful to redirect the user to the relevant spot within the app for that push notification .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this code to find out if my Trigger.io app was opened by a Parse push notification:

```
var appLastResumed = new Date();

window.forge.event.appResumed.addListener(function() {
  window.appLastResumed = new Date();
  // additional code that runs when the app is resumed
});

window.forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function() {
  // this event fires every time a user clicks on a push notification 
  // no matter whether the app is already opened or not
  // so we need to detect whether this happened right after an appResumed event

  setTimeout( function() { // make sure the appResumed event is fired first
    if (new Date().getTime() - window.appLastResumed.getTime() < 1000) {
      // app was opened by a push notification
      // insert your code here
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

Originally posted this answer earlier on [Any way to figure out if the app is opened directly or because of a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689092/any-way-to-figure-out-if-the-app-is-opened-directly-or-because-of-a-notification/13697846)